# How to insert image file to MySql db using Struts 2

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, struts2

I've tried inserting image file to MySQL db using Struts2 but I'm getting below error.

```
ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "execute" failed for object com.motorola.action.LicenseAction@569b1c56 [java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mysql/jdbc/ServerPreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V is abstract]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1556)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:96)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:88)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:423)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:369)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:436)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:134)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:134)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:199)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:88)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:157)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:201)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:53)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:577)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mysql/jdbc/ServerPreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V is abstract
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setBlob(ServerPreparedStatement.java)
    at com.motorola.dao.FileUploadDAO.save(FileUploadDAO.java:28)
    at com.motorola.action.LicenseAction.execute(LicenseAction.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544)
    ... 82 more
/-- Encapsulated exception ------------\
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mysql/jdbc/ServerPreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V is abstract
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setBlob(ServerPreparedStatement.java)
    at com.motorola.dao.FileUploadDAO.save(FileUploadDAO.java:28)
    at com.motorola.action.LicenseAction.execute(LicenseAction.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:96)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:88)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:423)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:369)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:436)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:134)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:134)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:199)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:88)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:157)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:201)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:53)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:577)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

Below is my view, action class, POJO and DAO class code.

**licUpload.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>

<html>
<head>
 
<link href="Css/motoCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
<meta http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    </head>
        
    <body style="background-color:#4682B4">
    
    <s:form name="licUploadForm" action="imageupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple" >
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="190" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="30%" class="login" style="background-repeat: no-repeat">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="60" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td colspan="2"><strong>License Upload</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                                                     <td align="right" height="35" style="font-size: 13px;">Licence ID</td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<s:textfield name="licID"  id="licID"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" style="font-size: 13px;">Start Date</td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <s:textfield name="startDate" id="startDate"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                                     <td align="right" height="35" style="font-size: 13px;">End Date</td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                     <s:textfield name="endDate"  id="endDate"/>
                                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" height="35" style="font-size: 13px;">Upload License</td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<s:file name="license" label="Select license" size="40" />
                                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="40" colspan="2" align="center">
                                 <s:submit class="button" value="Upload" />
                                 <s:submit class="button" value="Cancel"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        
                        
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            
    </s:form>




    </body>
     <HEAD>
           
</HEAD>
</html>
```

**LicenseAction.java:**

```
package com.motorola.action;

import java.io.File;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import com.motorola.dao.FileUploadDAO;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.motorola.pojo.LicensePOJO;

public class LicenseAction extends ActionSupport {
    
    private String licID;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private File license;
    
    public String getLicID() {
        return licID;
    }
    public void setLicID(String licID) {
        this.licID = licID;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public File getLicense() {
        return license;
    }
    public void setLicense(File license) {
        this.license = license;
    }

    
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        
        System.out.println("inside licenseAction");
        HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        int i=FileUploadDAO.save(this);
        if(i>0){  
            return "success";  
            }  
            return "error";
    }
    
}
```

**FileUploadDAO.java:**

```
package com.motorola.dao;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import com.motorola.action.LicenseAction;

import dbconnecetion.DBConnection;

public class FileUploadDAO {
    
    public static int save(LicenseAction lm){  
        int status=0;  
        Connection con =  DBConnection.getConnection();
        
        try{  
                System.out.println("inside FileUploadDAO");  
                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into customer_license_table(license_id,lic_start_date,lic_end_date,license_copy) values(?,?,?,?)");  
                ps.setString(1,lm.getLicID());
                ps.setString(2, lm.getStartDate());
                ps.setString(3, lm.getEndDate());
                
                // for inserting pdf in database
                System.out.println("input stream is*****"+lm.getLicense());
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(lm.getLicense());
                System.out.println("input stream is*****"+inputStream);
                ps.setBlob(4, inputStream);
                
                int i = ps.executeUpdate();  
                status=ps.executeUpdate();  
          
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
            return status;  
        }

}
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">


<struts>
      <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    
 
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">    
        <action name="loginSubmit" class="com.motorola.action.LoginAction">
                <result name="admin">/AdminUser.jsp</result>
                <result name="service">/ServiceCenter.jsp</result>
                <result name="customer">/RequestManagement.jsp</result>
                <result name="ERROR">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        <action name="addCustomer" class="com.motorola.action.CustomerMgtAction">
                <result name="success">/CustomerManagement.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>        
        </action>
        
        <action name="requestMgt" class="com.motorola.action.RequestMgtAction">
                <result name="success">/RequestManagement.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        <action name="viewReqDetails" class="com.motorola.action.RequestMgtDetailsAction">
                <result name="success">/RequestMgmtDetails.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/RequestManagement.jsp</result>        
        </action>
        
        <action name="viewAllCustomers" class="com.motorola.action.ViewCustomersAction">
                <result name="success">/ViewCustomers.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/AdminUser.jsp</result>        
        </action>
        
        <action name="acceptCustDetails" class="com.motorola.action.UpdateRequestStatusAction">
                <result name="success">/RequestManagement.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/RequestMgmtDetails.jsp</result>       
        </action>
        
        <action name="viewLicense" class="com.motorola.action.ViewLicenseAction">
                <result name="success">/ViewLicense.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        <action name="imageupload" class="com.motorola.action.LicenseAction">
                <result name="success">/ViewCustomers.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        
        
    </package>

</struts>
```

I tried with `preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex,InputStream x);`
but unable to insert image file to db

Answer (score 0):

To insert image you need to create an image first. The file you have uploaded may contain an image data, but it's not obligatory unless you can properly validate the data that you uploaded.

When the image is created, then you can decode it to the buffer. The buffer should contain all rendered data. Use this data for the `Blob`.

`Blob` data type should be used on the database column.